# multiple image tap on change but no repeat of image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a multiple image and it changed on tap, maybe around 35 images and no repeat and a popup stack when the last card is surface.

currently i only manage to create a new class which once i enter, it will randomly show me a image.

thanks in advance.

I am very new to flutter, hope some one can give me some help on this.

```
class _SettingpageState extends State<Settingpage> {
  List<String> imagelist = [
    'lib/images/image1.png',
    'lib/images/image2.png',
    'lib/images/image3.png',
    'lib/images/image4.png',
    'lib/images/image5.png',
  ];
  late String imagePath;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    imagelist.shuffle(); //shuffle over here
    var imagePath = imagelist[0]; //store random image over here
    return Container(
      width: 80,
      height: 50,
      child: Image.asset(imagePath),

      //show random image
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: In your model take one more variable " isViewed:false" and when you tap on the image set it to true, once all images are viewed then reset the array and set all false.

Comment: thanks for the reply , cause i am very new to flutter or even coding , what the steps i need to do ? i have a class on the images. Do i need create another class for others?